# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 3D Perspective

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I am new to OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android, I have managed to use Matrix.orthoM to create an orthographic view, but I am currently having problems trying to get a perspective view. I know that using LWJGL I can use GLU.gluPerspective to achieve this, and I know that you can do this on Android using OpenGL ES 1.0, but I don't know how to get this working in the same way in OpenGL ES 2.0. I found out that there was a way to do this using Matrix.perspectiveM, but this is only available for API 14, so this is not really suitable. Is there another way I can get a perspective view working?

Thank you.

Comment: Please state your solution, you said you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own perspective matrix. See this [link](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/perspective-projection-matrix/) it can help you

function sample to define the matrix(not tested):

```
void setperspectivemat(float[] mat, float near, float far, float fov)
{

 float scale = 1 / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov * 0.5));
 mat[0] = scale;
 mat[5] = scale;
 mat[10] = - far / (far - near);
 mat[11] = - far * near / (far - near);
 mat[14] = - 1;
 mat[15] = 0;
}
```

Comment: I had a look, I tried the code above, and it displays something, but its not quite right, it looks like it might be very close up.

Comment: The aspect ratio of the drawing surface should also go into the perspective matrix calculation.

Comment: It's true, it's only work for aspect ratio of 1. You can always write your own frustrum and perspective function. See the source code in the end of this [article](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/opengl-perspective-projection-matrix/)